# How to measure time for the each task running in parallel processing?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have a set of items and split the items based on the batch sizes, e.g., 1000 items, and will pass the item to parallel processing. How do we know what thread is spawning and measuring the time each batch set's performance log runs in parallel?

Below is the sample code.

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var chunks = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).Batch(1000);

        for each (var item in chunks)
        {
            RunParallel(item);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static List<int> RunParallel(IEnumerable<int> chunkItems)
    {
        ConcurrentBag<int> bag = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
        Parallel.ForEach(chunkItems, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, (item) =>
        {
            //Consider this as db processing. 
            bag.Add(item); 
        });

        return bag.ToList();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Batch<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, long batchSize)
    {
        var items = new TSource[batchSize];
        var count = 0;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            items[count++] = item;
            if (count == batchSize)
            {
                yield return items;
                items = new TSource[batchSize];
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        if (count > 0)
            yield return items.Take(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a timer around `Parallel.ForEach`? Anyway, if the final code does write to a database and it is doing that using Task based methods  `Parallel.ForEach` isn't a suitable option as it does not work together with Task based methods. You'll could use `Task.WhenAll`

Comment: As Peter Bons has already mentioned `Parallel.XYZ` were design for CPU bound operations not for I/O bound. In case of I/O operations lowering the number of concurrent calls to 4 would be really dramatic. In case CPU bound operations the number of cores are the limiting factor. On the other hand the I/O bound ops are controlled by the network driver, which could handle way more operations concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Parallel_ForEach__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Action___0_System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelLoopState_System_Int64__) of the Parallel.ForEach which passes the index of the current iteration:
`Parallel.ForEach(list, (item,state,index) => {YourFunction(index);}  );`

And you can use a [stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-5.0) inside the function that you want to measure it's execution time.

```
 Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
 stopWatch.Start();
 //your logic goes here
 stopWatch.Stop();
 //Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
 TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

Comment: This is not going to work. StopWatch is not thread safe...

Comment: @Bart stopwatch is fine in this instance because it is _inside_ the function, at this point it is a synchronous operation. Thread safety as you have referenced it here relates to accessing the object across multiple threads, that is not going on here.